# Purchasing a certificate for WCF communication?

Tags: windows, wcf, x509certificate, makecert

For a long time I have been using "makecert.exe" to create my own certificate used for WCF communication between two clients.

Now and then I get error reports from users which have a higher security/validation procedures and errors are raised like this:

*UntrustedRoot: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider*

Now, I want to get rid of this and purchase a certificate. Preferably with a very long expiration date. But the questions are;

1. what type of certificate do I need? (what is the name of the certificate type)
2. where can I buy this? I would appreciate at least one line so I can verify certificate type as well.